# When migrating from iPhoto to Photos my trainer deleted Photos library rather than iPhotos library

Tags: photos

OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.5... When migrating from iPhoto to Photos my trainer deleted Photos library rather than iPhotos library. What needs to be done to correct?

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Answer (score 1):

Just re-migrate. Open Photos and it will ask you if you want to migrate your iPhoto Library.